# Which of the following sentences is correct, thinking in a context related with work?

Tags: sentence

I have the following question, i am thinking in a context related with the work,

Which of the following sentences is correct?

```
I am here to substitute Tom.
I am the substitute of Tom.
```

The context is that recently a person who used to work in my company, left this company, and I was hired to substitute him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are awkward. The first should include the word *for*: "I am here to substitute *for* Tom". The second would be better worded as "I am Tom's substitute."

However, [*substitute*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/substitute) in a work context usually indicates a temporary position. Consider *substitute teacher* for example:

> A substitute teacher is a person who teaches a school class when the regular teacher is unavailable; e.g., because of illness, personal leave, or other reasons.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_teacher)

It's idiomatic to say that you are Tom's *replacement*.

> **Replacement** *noun*
>   1.1 A person or thing that takes the place of another: *please stay until we find a replacement for you*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/replacement)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, but I have a doubt about it, the correct sentence in this context would be: I am the Tom's replacement or I am here to replace for Tom ?, I get confuse about the use of "for" in the second sentence.

Comment: @user138717 The appropriate sentence would be "I am Tom's replacement." You could say, "I am replacing Tom" or "I am here to replace Tom". But "*for* Tom" means something like "on Tom's behalf". It requires something after *replace*, which changes the meaning of the sentence altogether - e.g. "I am here to replace a light bulb for Tom."

Comment: I already understand, thanks a lot for the support.